# Query sharepoint list from MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Ok i have a fairly simple request, but i have been searching for some hours now and can't seem to find a simple answer to what i feel should be a fairly simple task.

I have built an intranet site for our business using dot net & MVC this runs on a separate server to the sharepoint site. All i want to do is get a list of documents from a given sharepoint library and display links to their urls which will redirect the end user to that document from my intranet site - this will vary depending on the users dept.

So i was looking at the jquery AJAX route, but then i realise sharepoint wont allow me javascript queries from a different domain.

So next route is backend dot net pass the data to the view and display that way, but i want to use the servers sharepoint authentication without entering username and password in the code/manually.

Am i missing something simple? I don't want to waste a lot of time on something i thought should be fairly simple.. anyone fancy pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it wasn't incredibly easy but i did get it done like this if anyone wants to know :p sp 2013 using Rest api using server credentials to connect to sharepoint and retrieve documents Name, Sharepoint url and icon.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net

Public Class SPDocumentLibrary

  Public Property Files As List(Of SPDocument)

  Public Sub New()

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(
    "http://sharepointserver/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list')/items?$expand=File&$select=File/Name,OData__dlc_DocIdUrl/Url&$orderby=Title&$top=99999&orderby=File/Name"
                          ), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "GET"
    request.ContentType = "text/xml"
    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim xd As XDocument = XDocument.Load(readStream)
    response.Close()
    readStream.Close()

    Dim d As XNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    Dim x As XNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"

    Dim docs As IEnumerable(Of SPDocument) = _
    From doc As XElement In xd.Root.Elements(x + "entry") _
    Select New SPDocument With {.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(doc.Descendants(d + "Name").Value), .Url = doc.Descendants(d + "Url").Value, .icon = IconFromExtension(Path.GetExtension(doc.Descendants(d + "Name").Value).ToLower)}

    Me.Files = docs.ToList()

End Sub

Private Function IconFromExtension(ext As String) As String

    If ext Like ".doc*" Then
        Return "icdoc.png"
    ElseIf ext Like ".xls*" Then
        Return "icxls.png"
    ElseIf ext Like ".ppt*" Then
        Return "icppt.png"
    ElseIf ext = ".pdf" Then
        Return "icpdf.png"
    ElseIf ext = ".msg" Then
        Return "icmsg.png"
    ElseIf ext Like ".htm*" Then
        Return "ichtm.gif"
    ElseIf ext Like ".rtf" Then
        Return "icrtf.gif"
    ElseIf ext Like ".dot*" Then
        Return "icdot.png"
    ElseIf ext Like ".xlt*" Then
        Return "icxlt.png"
    Else
        Return "icgen.gif"
    End If

  End Function

End Class

Public Class SPDocument
  Property Name As String
  Property Url As String
  Property icon As String
End Class
```

Comment: :I have a similar requirement to connect to a url(sharepoint ) from mvc intranet application. URl returns html and want to read data from the page and populate those on my mvc view. I tried Can you suggest me

Comment: I tried the below ajax request but it gives status = 0 errir $.ajax({
            url: 'http://XXX.aspx?k=yyya&exact=true',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text/html',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(12);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('1Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                } 
            }
        });